# Strange Anchor Tag Behavior - Awful

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this is silly but just listen, I have this HTML code in my page but when I open this in my Chrome browser it show strange behavior (view image). Yes I tried it again by *opening in IE browser* but same results, the anchor tag not working as it should. Also I tried it by *disabling and removing all my Javascript files and codes*, but still.

Any help would be appreciated :)

**Image:**
[image]

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="post">
    <a href="#0">
        <div class="post-image">
            <img src="img/jan-erik-waider-1639.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-data align-center">
            <a class="post-category" href="#0">Personality</a>
            <div class="post-title">
                <h2>We swallow it fast, we choke. We get in our lungs</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p>Awesome get some in our lungs, we. That's clear. We swallow it too fast, That's also clear. But for some
                    reason, we choke....</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: ... So what's the problem? That would be helpful.

Comment: And how should it work? What are you expecting from it to do?

Comment: Do not embed `a` tag inside another `a` tag

Comment: Please view the image, its not working properly. i opened the ANCHOR tag after that <div class="post"> and closed it before closing this div..but in image it's not working like i written in code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think the problem is that the `a` is not wrapping the content _correctly_

Comment: Also as you can see in my HTML code there is only one tag after  <div class="post-data align-center"> with class="post-category" but in image there is an empty tag too. i don't know from where that come.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested anchor elements are forbidden in HTML syntax. On the practical side, browsers effectively enforce this restriction in their parsing rules.

[You can find a detailed reference here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes nested anchor elements are forbidden in HTML syntax.

You can't put a  tag inside of an  tag for doctypes prior to HTML5. But you could do something like this.

```
<a href="#0">
   <span id="bestprice">
   </span>
</a>
```